# Does the sorcerer at-will Lightning Strike trigger the feat Focusing Spellfury?

Tags: dnd-4e, feats, sorcerer

The sorcerer at-will attack [Lightning Strike](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/power.aspx?id=3005)<sup>[DDI]</sup> (AP page 28) allows you to damage a secondary creature after hitting with the original attack.

For the purpose of the feat [Focusing Spellfury](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/feat.aspx?id=1138)<sup>[DDI]</sup> (AP page 127), does the damage inflicted upon another creature with Lightning Strike count as a "hit" so you would then get the bonus damage?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**No**,

To be a hit you need to roll the d20 and get above the target defense.  Any ancillary effects like secondary damage from [Lightning Strike](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/power.aspx?id=3005) do not count as hits for the purposes of Focusing Spellfury.

From the DDI definition of [Hit](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/glossary.aspx?id=128):

> If the attack roll is higher than or equal to the defense score, the attack hits and deals damage, has a special effect, or both.

If the hit gave a secondary attack, like [Chaos Bolt](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/power.aspx?id=5260), then that bonus damage could be applied assuming it met the other requirements of Focusing Spellfury.